# Cufon text replacement and IE8 standards mode

Tags: web-development, javascript, internet-explorer, fonts

I have a perculiar issue. In IE8 standards mode text replaced by `Cufon.Replace` <strike>works roughly 50% of the time, the rest of the time</strike> the DOM modifications are there (viewed through IE developer toolbar in IE8) but no text actually appears.

Sometimes have to refresh the page a number of times to be able to recreate it; others it works first page load - this is the case for a site you have never visited.

The Cufon.Replace isn't throwing an exception or producing any other issue. Googling hasn't helped - others mention issues in IE8, but this lack of text is permanent and not just a slow loading issue.

**EDIT**: Interestingly wrapping the `Cufon.replace` in the `$(document).ready(function(){});` stopped it from ever working! Something in the DOM is to blame... I presume

**EDIT 2**: Applying the Cufon.replace manually once the page has fully loaded works. This is strange. Is there a later event than ready?

Answer (score 2):

You do say it's permanent, and not just a slowness to update. But...:

- Does the second call to Cufon, as described in ["Step 4 – Make Internet Explorer behave" in the docs](http://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Usage) help?
- Does the HTML validate?
- Are you using an "advanced" selector so that a selector engine (like jQuery's) needs to be loaded, and could there be a race condition with this load?

If none of the above helps, then maybe you should whip up a minimalistic demo page showing the issue, and write to the Cufón mailing list.

Comment: 1. Yes, it is permanent.
2. No - unlikely to; issues with image tags - so not related to Cufon.
3. Yes, that it is why I was wrapping it in `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`